# SpringApplicationContextLoader ignores Application class

Tags: rest, groovy, spring-boot

The `SpringApplicationContextLoader` assumes that the application is either using 100% XML or 100% Java config. This is because `@ContextConfiguration` allows either a list of classes or locations/value, not both. If any is specified, `SpringApplicationContextLoader` ignores the Application class that creates and starts the SpringApplication.

Trying to make Boot work with a 100% Groovy/no-XML pet project, I ran across the above issue. My Application class has `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` annotations on it, the former required by Boot to set up a Web server. The later I had to keep because of [SPR-11627](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11627). On the other hand, if I omitted the locations/value on `@ContextConfiguration`, dependencies weren't set up (duh!).

I give the code below along with a patch that I locally made to `SpringApplicationContextLoader`. If there's a better way, please let me know.

**MovieDatabaseRESTClientIntegrationTest.groovy**

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner)
@ContextConfiguration(value = ['classpath:client-config.groovy', 'classpath:integ-test-config.groovy'],
        loader = PatchedSpringApplicationContextLoader)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MovieDatabaseApplication)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
class MovieDatabaseRESTClientIntegrationTest {
```

**MovieDatabaseApplication.groovy**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
class MovieDatabaseApplication {
```

**SpringApplicationContextLoader.java fix**

```
private Set<Object> getSources(MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) {
        Set<Object> sources = new LinkedHashSet<Object>();
        sources.addAll(Arrays.asList(mergedConfig.getClasses()));
        sources.addAll(Arrays.asList(mergedConfig.getLocations()));

    /* The Spring application class may have annotations on it too. If such a class is declared on the test class,
    * add it as a source too. */
    SpringApplicationConfiguration springAppConfig = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(mergedConfig.getTestClass(),
            SpringApplicationConfiguration.class);

    if (springAppConfig != null) {
        sources.addAll(Arrays.asList(springAppConfig.classes()));
    }

    if (sources.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "No configuration classes or locations found in @SpringApplicationConfiguration. "
                        + "For default configuration detection to work you need Spring 4.0.3 or better (found "
                        + SpringVersion.getVersion() + ").");
    }
    return sources;
}
```

Also posted on Spring forum.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I don't think there is any support for `beans{}` configuration in `@ContextConfiguration` and `@SpringContextConfiguration` is just an extension of that. A feature request in JIRA would be appropriate. Also there has never been any support for mixed configuration format (as the entry point at least) - you always have to choose either XML or `@Configuration`, or else supply your own `ContextLoader`. You also shouldn't have both `@ContextConfiguration` and `@SpringContextConfiguration` on the same class (the behaviour is undefined).

Comment: There's actually some support for `beans {}`. The GroovyBeanDefinitionReader is invoked and it does a decent job at reading simple files. There's a currently a JIRA open [SPR-11233](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11233) for providing first class support.
I had to use both `@ContextConfiguration` and `@SpringContextConfiguration` because of this bug [spring-boot-603](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/603). I submitted a pull request.

Comment: More specifically, the `SpringApplicationContextLoader` doesn't set up a web configuration unless it finds the `@SpringContextConfiguration`. On the other hand, it doesn't support loading from `beans {}` so I'm forced to use `@ContextConfiguration` as well.

Comment: Actually `SpringApplicationContextLoader` does support loading from `beans{}` but you can't mix `classes=` and `locations=`. This is for historical reasons, and there's no reason it couldn't work, but it's not a Boot feature since it's tied to the underlying Spring Test implementation.

Comment: On a separate note, I'm really interested in Spring Boot; I think it has a lot of growth potential. Can I help somehow by fixing bugs, small ones to start with?